How can I adapt a Laravel query?
Help please...
These are my migrations​
 // Test 1 table
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('test1s', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('desc')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }



next...

// Test 2 table
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('test2s', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('desc')->nullable();
            $table->foreignId('test2_id')->references('id')->on('test1s')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


next...


   // Test 3 table
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('test3s', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('desc')->nullable();
            $table->foreignId('test3_id')->references('id')->on('test2s')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Here are my models and methods in them
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test1 extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function method1(){
       return $this->hasMany(Test2::class, 'test2_id', 'id')->with('method2');
   }


namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test2 extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function method2(){
      return $this->hasMany(Test3::class, 'test3_id', 'id');
    }
}

Here's controller
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Test1;


class HomeController extends Controller
{
 
    public function index()
    {
         $res= Test1::with('method1')->get();
           return view('home' , compact(['res']));
    }
}


The tables are filled with test data, no more than 10 records... At the same time, through the debugger it shows 5 queries and 20 models... If you add records, the number of queries remains 5, and the number of models increases... Moreover, if there are about 1000 records, then There will be more than 10,000 models... Is it possible to optimize this somehow? How?
Upd
Here's my blade
@foreach ($res as $result)
    <h2>{{ $result->name }}</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($result->method1 as $res2)
            <li>
                <p>{{ $res2->name }}</p>
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($res2->method2 as $res3)
                        <li>
                            <p>{{ $res3->name }}</p>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach


Here is a screenshot of the debugger
enter image description here

I don't really understand what you want to achieve. Seems logical that the models are returned. If you use blade views, you do not need the with,  so they only query when you use them. and you can paginate your query: ->paginate(50) instead of ->get().

Show what your blade looks like

Updated the question

The issue might be related to how you defined your relationships, I had a similar issue when I started programming because I just fetched all and Eloquent, for some reason, went into some circular motion and fetched some tables repeatedly because it had relationships with it..
For this to work, update these migrations:
// Test 2 table
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('test2s', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('desc')->nullable();
        $table->foreignId('test1_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

test3 migration:
// Test 3 table

public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('test3s', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('desc')->nullable();
        $table->foreignId('test2_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

then the models
Test1 model:
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test1 extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function test2s()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Test2::class);
    }
}

Test 2 model:
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test2 extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function test3s()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Test3::class);
    }
}

Test 3 model:
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test3 extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // you can define inverse relationship also
}

Eager load the relationships without nesting so you reduce the number of queries:
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Test1;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $res = Test1::with('test2s.test3s')->get();
        return view('home', compact('res'));
    }
}

and then! blade file update:
@foreach ($res as $test1)
    <h2>{{ $test1->name }}</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($test1->test2s as $test2)
            <li>
                <p>{{ $test2->name }}</p>
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($test2->test3s as $test3)
                        <li>
                            <p>{{ $test3->name }}</p>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach


Thank you, the migration code has become better, but in terms of the number of models loaded, nothing has changed. If the test3 table has 8 records, then the debugger shows 8 calls to the Test3 model... I'm just starting to learn Laravel, I don't know, maybe this is how it should be? But I'm worried that if there is a large database with thousands of records and they need to be loaded, what will happen to the load? What will happen to the application?

Yeah, it doesn't do 8 calls into the test3 table (model), it just goes once into the database and pulls out the data you requested. After you have a huge dataset, you will optimize your queries to fetch paginated data from the database with only the data you want with it. For example, 25 results from test2 with related data from test3 table, so it won't hurt your performance.
After you will learn many more ways to query data, so no worries :D

Thanks for the answer. I will study further)

Let's assume this users-posts-comments situation:
To optimize the Laravel Eloquent query and avoid many model instances in the view, you can eager load the comments along with the posts and users. This will reduce the number of queries executed and improve the performance of your application.
Here's how you can modify your query and view:
Query Optimization
Load the comments along with the posts and users using eager loading:
$users = User::with('posts.comments')->get();

View Optimization
You can directly access the comments through the posts that are already eager-loaded, avoiding the need for additional queries:
@foreach($users as $user)
    @foreach($user->posts as $post)
        <h4>Comments from {{ $user->name }}</h4>
        @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
            <li>{{ $comment->comment }}</li>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach

This approach ensures that all the necessary data is fetched in a single query, reducing the load on your database and improving the performance of your application.

Thanks, but it didn't help. The number of calls to models is not high. (
My blade is in updating the question.

Do share your Laravel blade code

Please update your question

updated the question. Initially there were 22 requests for models, and that remains the case.

Sorry. The screenshot was taken before the new data was added to the database, and with the new data added, the models became 22, not 20...
